# Pairing multiple images in javascript (with multiple options for each)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random, filter

**Edit**: Since I'm just planning my approach to the project, I have no code to show for it. My question is more about how i could approach the problem (arrays, objects or if there are smarter ways to do it) than about the actual code. Since I'm pretty new Im looking for a "way in" how I could tackle the project and look at tutorials.

*(Since I'm pretty new to coding I'm trying to solidify the basics of html/css/js by building my own projects. With this project my problem is finding my way in, since I struggle with finding the correct mechanics, so I cant find any tutorials because i dont know where to start)*

**The project**

I'm trying to build a project which pairs 3 images ("background", "base" and "addition"), starting from one which is selected.
*For example:* I'm selecting in image with the "background" woods and it will pair it with a small river as "base" and foxes as "addition".
If the user doesn't like the pairing, he can click a btn and it will pair the same selected image (in this case the wood) with other two compatible images (for example: a mossy stone and squirrels).
However: it wouldn pair my selected image, which in this case is a wood with a desert floor and dolphins.
The user also could start by selecting a "addition", for example a crab, which will be paired with a beach and smaller pebbles.

**The problem**

I'm pretty sure that the main focus with this project should be on arrays.
I thought i could do 3 arrays (one for the background, one for the base and one for the addition) and from there just pair random values from the different arrays. However, should i make 3 arrays for every probability or is there a way I could filter the pairs I want and the pairs i dont want?

An other approach i thought of was to let every image in the array be an object, so that i can assign attributes (for example: climate, color, sea level..) to the objects and filter them based on that.
In this case however I'm struggling with the code to first filter the correct pairings and then select a random pairing from those which were selected.

*Every bit of help is appreciated,

thank you!*

Comment: Hi, what's missing is the part of the code that doesn't work - your existing attempt - and in what way it failed.

Comment: You posted a thoughtful & well-reasoned project and problem statement... but you've gotta post your code or it really isn't possible to provide much assistance. Please post your code attempt, including relevant HTML, CSS & JS and I'm sure plenty of folks will be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The thing is that i have no code at the moment because Im trying to find a way to aproach the project. My question is less about the code than it is about the approach I should take (if I should do it with arrays, objects, or if there would be other smarter ways).